# How to make telegram bot to remove links?

Tags: bots, telegram-bot

As i know telegram bot can't delete any message in group but i saw recently a group when i share a link it deleted immediately and i'm pretty sure it wasn't a human do that with that speed.Also in another group i see a robot that doesn't have _bot and it was real user but treat as a bot and i'm pretty sure it wasn't human (i tested it).So i search a lot in goole but all links related to bot api of telegram
So anybody knows about it? maybe someone compile telergam source client and does something that it can remove links from a group

Comment: it was a telegram bot. i saw many bots can delete any message from groups . you can test this https://storebot.me/bot/antilinkforgroup_groupbot

Comment: The bot you mentioned @samnikzad doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @egghead because comment is for  `May 9 '17`

Comment: @samnikzad that's why, it saves the people that are looking for something like that some time

Comment: @egghead this bot is old. maybe removed now